# Creating an array from values in a text file with powershell

Tags: arrays, file, powershell, extract

I have a text file with this content:

```
SEGMENTS="worker01 worker02 worker03 worker04"
WORKER_SEGMENTS="worker01 worker02 worker03 worker04"
#SEGMENTS="worker01"
#WORKER_SEGMENTS="worker01"
```

I read this file from another powershell script and I want to to create an array of the `WORKER_SEGMENTS` values. I have gotten so far:

```
$workers = Get-Content $strPath"\worker\conf\segments.conf" | Where-Object {$_ -like "*WORKER_SEGMENTS*"}
Write-Host $workers
```

This yields:

```
PS Q:\mles\etl-i_test\rc> .\etl.ps1
WORKER_SEGMENTS="worker01 worker02 worker03 worker04" #WORKER_SEGMENTS="worker01"
```

I only need the `worker01`, `worker02`, `worker03`, `worker04` from `WORKER_SEGMENTS` (without the leading #) as an array. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Get-Content .\t.txt | 
? { $_ -like "WORKER_SEGMENTS*" } | 
% { $_ -replace '.*?"([^"]*)".*', '$1' -split " " }

worker01
worker02
worker03
worker04
```

Or

```
Get-Content .\t.txt | 
? { $_ -like "WORKER_SEGMENTS*" } | 
% { ($_ -split '"')[1] -split ' ' }

worker01
worker02
worker03
worker04
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer I can understand the most. What does `% { ($_ -split '"')[1] -split ' ' }` do?

Comment: It gets content between the first two `"` (which is the workernames), then it turns the names into an array by splitting on space. The first sample does the same using regex.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Get-Content $strPath"\worker\conf\segments.conf" | 
    Select-String 'WORKER_SEGMENTS\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"' | 
    Foreach {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value -split ' '} | 
    Foreach {$ht=@{}}{$ht.$_=$null}
$ht
```

By using a hashtable we can eliminate duplicate entries fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

you may have to tweak it a bit to get exactly what you want, but this should get you headed in the right direction:

```
$workers = (Get-Content $strPath"\worker\conf\segments.conf" | ?{$_ -like 'Worker_Segments*'}).Split('"')[1].Split(' ')
```